# Вывод дочерних страниц в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress. Есть структура: `страница 1 / дочерняя страница / дочерняя страница (дочерней страницы)`. Я вывела на `страница 1` список всех дочерних страниц, но не получается под каждой дочерней страницей вывести её дочерних страниц. Попытаюсь объяснить наглядно:

```
Страница 1

  Дочерняя страница
    дочерняя страница
    дочерняя страница

  Дочерняя страница
    дочерняя страница
    дочерняя страница
```

Вот код которым я вывела дочерние страницы первого уровня:

```
$stati_children = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
  'posts_per_page' => -1
  )
);

if($stati_children->have_posts()) :
  while($stati_children->have_posts()): $stati_children->the_post();
      echo '<h2>'.get_the_title().'</h2>';
      echo '<p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>';
      echo '<p><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.Подробнее.'</a></p>';
  endwhile;
endif; wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [get_pages()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_pages). Собственно разница в том что `'post_parent'` в `WP_Query` выведет только дочерние страницы от Вашего основного родителя, в свою же очередь `'child_of'` выведет все дочерние (дочерние дочерних и так далее).

```
$args = array(
    'child_of' => get_the_ID(),
    'post_type' => 'page',
); 
$pages = get_pages($args);

foreach($pages as $page){
    // ваш код...
}
```

Так же если нужно, можете использовать с setup_postdata();

```
foreach($pages as $post){
    setup_postdata($post);
    //...
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Мне нужно вывести только дочерние двух уровней.